# Returning a NodeEntity from neo4j doesn't contain relationships or connected nodes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

I'm setting up a P.O.C. using Neo4j, and *technically* have everything I need working but would like it set up properly.

As a quick overview - I can create nodes and relationships, and traverse the graph (i.e. return all features available in a specific market) so I know these nodes/relationships have been created.

However, when I query to simply return a Node based on ID, it returns ONLY the data for that node - and not any relationships or connected nodes, for example, the markets its available in.

I've looked various places online that have not only a Node returned but also the subsequent nodes - though I follow what they're doing I cant seem to get it to work with mine.

Feature Repository:

```java
    @Repository
    public interface FeatureRepository<T extends Feature> extends Neo4jRepository<T, Long> {
    ...
    }
```

Colour Repository:

```java
    @Repository
    public interface ColourRepository extends FeatureRepository<Colour>{
        @Query("CREATE(feat:Colour:Feature {marketingDesc:{marketing}, engineeringDesc:{engineering}, code:{code}})")
        Colour createColour(@Param("marketing") String marketingDesc, @Param("engineering") String engineeringDesc, @Param("code") String code);

        @Query("MATCH (c:Colour {code:{colourCode}}) MATCH (c)-[:AVAILABLE_IN]->(market) RETURN c AS colour, COLLECT(market) AS markets")
        Colour getColourByCode(@Param("colourCode") String colourCode);

        Colour findByCode(@Param("code") String code);
    }
```

Feature Entity:

```java
    @NodeEntity(label = "Feature")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Feature {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String marketingDesc;
        private String engineeringDesc;
        @Index(unique = true)
        private String code;

        @Relationship(type = "HAS_OPTION", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
        private List<Option> options = new ArrayList<>();

        @Relationship(type = "AVAILABLE_IN")
        private List<Market> markets = new ArrayList<>();

        @Relationship(type = "HAS_PREREQUISITE", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
        private List<Prerequisite> prerequisites = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Colour Entity:

```java
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NodeEntity(label = "Colour")
    public class Colour extends Feature {
    }
```

Market Entity:

```java
    @NodeEntity(label = "Market")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Market {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Index(unique = true)
        private String code;
        private String market;

        @Relationship(type = "AVAILABLE_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
        private List<Option> features = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Relationship Entity (for features to be connected to markets they can be bought in):

```java
    @RelationshipEntity(type = "AVAILABLE_IN")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Available {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long Id;
        private List<String> availableIn = new ArrayList<>();

        @StartNode
        private Feature feature;
        @EndNode
        private Market market;
    }
```

Controller:

```java
    @RestController
    public class ConfigController {

        private final Handler configHandler;

        public ConfigController(Handler configHandler) {
            this.configHandler = configHandler;
        }

     @PostMapping(path = "/create/colour", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public SimpleResponse createColour(@RequestBody Colour request) {
            ColourService service = new ColourService(configHandler);
            Colour created = service.createColour(request);
            return SimpleResponse.builder().result("Created:", created).build();
        }

        @PostMapping(path = "/create/market", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public SimpleResponse createMarket(@RequestBody Market request) {
            MarketService service = new MarketService(configHandler);
            Market created = service.createMarket(request);
            return SimpleResponse.builder().result("Created", created).build();
        }

        @PostMapping(path = "/create/relationship/availableIn", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public SimpleResponse createAvailableInRelationship(@RequestBody OptionAvailInRequest request){
            RelationshipService service = new RelationshipService(configHandler);
            Object result = service.createAvailableInRelationship(request);
            return SimpleResponse.builder().result("Result:", result).build();
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "/colour/{code}")
        public SimpleResponse getColourByCode(@PathVariable(value = "code") String code) {
            ColourService service = new ColourService(configHandler);
            Colour colour = service.getColourByCode(code);
            return SimpleResponse.builder().result("Colour:", colour).build();
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "/features/available/{mrktCode}")
        public SimpleResponse getFeaturesInMarket(@PathVariable(value = "mrktCode") String mrktCode){
            RelationshipService service = new RelationshipService(configHandler);
            Collection<Feature> features = service.getFeaturesInMarket(mrktCode);
            return SimpleResponse.builder().result("Features:", features).build();
        }
    }
```

Neo4jConfig file:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "package.location")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class Neo4jConfig {
        @Bean
        public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
            org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration =
                    new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder().build();


            return configuration;
        }

        @Bean
        public SessionFactory sessionFactory(org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration) {

            return new SessionFactory(configuration,"package.location");
        }

        @Bean
        public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        }
    }
```

So, for example, here I can create a Colour Node:

Example value:

```
{
  "code": "string",
  "engineeringDesc": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "marketingDesc": "string",
  "markets": [
    {
      "code": "string",
      "features": [
        {}
      ],
      "id": 0,
      "market": "string"
    }
  ],
  "options": [
    {}
  ],
  "prerequisites": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

What I send:

```
{
  "code": "BLU",
  "engineeringDesc": "Blue engineering",
  "marketingDesc": "Blue marketing"
}
```

And this creates a Colour Node successfully:

```
{
  "result": {
    "Created:": {
      "id": 0,
      "marketingDesc": "Blue marketing",
      "engineeringDesc": "Blue engineering",
      "code": "BLU",
      "options": [],
      "markets": [],
      "prerequisites": []
    }
  },
  "error": null
}
```

I can create a Market Node:
Example Value:

```
{
  "code": "string",
  "features": [
    {}
  ],
  "id": 0,
  "market": "string"
}
```

What I send:

```
{
  "code": "UB",
  "market": "England"
}
```

Which creates a Market Node successfully:

```
{
  "result": {
    "Created": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "UB",
      "market": "England",
      "features": []
    }
  },
  "error": null
}
```

I can then create a relationship between the two, to say that colour is available in that market:

```
{
  "featureCode": "BLU",
  "marketCode": "UB"
}
```

Which I can verify has been created by hitting:
localhost:8080/features/available/UB

```
{
  "result": {
    "Features:": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "marketingDesc": "Blue marketing",
        "engineeringDesc": "Blue engineering",
        "code": "BLU",
        "options": [],
        "markets": [],
        "prerequisites": []
      }
    ]
  },
  "error": null
}
```

However when I then go to return the Colour Node itself: 
localhost:8080/colour/BLU

```
{
  "result": {
    "Colour:": {
      "id": 0,
      "marketingDesc": "Blue marketing",
      "engineeringDesc": "Blue engineering",
      "code": "BLU",
      "options": [],
      "markets": [],
      "prerequisites": []
    }
  },
  "error": null
}
```

The 'markets' option is always null. I have tried custom queries and building queries using the neo4j helper (e.g. findByCode etc.), and every example I can find will sucessfully return the related nodes, but I cant seem to get mine to.

Can anyone help?
P.S. Please let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful for you to see. Been trying to get this sorted for days....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer to this question...

Feature Entity should have been:

```
    @Relationship(type = "AVAILABLE_IN")
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private Set<Available> markets = new HashSet<>();
```

Market Entity should have been:

```
    @Relationship(type = "AVAILABLE_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private Set<Available> features = new HashSet<>();
```

Which gets the markets section of the feature JSON no longer null...

Now I have the problem that there's an infinite recursion loop between the two classes, with a feature displaying the markets and the markets displaying the features

EDIT:

For anyone else with this/similar issues, I've found a really good github resource. 
[GitHub neo4j ogm walkthrough](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/neo4j-ogm-docs/src/main/asciidoc/reference/annotations.adoc)

Helped a lot.